# Bootable USB not booting anymore

Tags: windows-10, boot, usb

I created a bootable USB drive and I was able to boot from it and install the OS but surprisingly another similar computer will not boot from it.

The only thing I did in the intermediate was, copy some other files to the USB (large unrelated files just to empty space from another USB). Could this be a factor somehow why the system doesn't boot from it anymore?

Comment: It boots from the initial PC? I also do that(*copying unrelated files to an bootable drive*) but that doesn't affect my drives. It is a Windows bootable USB?

Comment: @TiagoCaldeira Thanks good to know. Yes it's Windows ghost image.

Answer (score 0):

Can other machines boot from it? Can the usb drive be detected in BIOS?

You have to change the boot order in BIOS,use the up and down arrows to the USB Flash Drive.
http://www.boot-disk.com/boot_priority.htm

Reset BIOS and try again. If it can't be detected in BIOS, it is possible the usb port or the usb is dead.